# Get all the machines in a SharePoint farm

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation

I'm writing a really big script which will get a lot of info from my farm. I'd like to make it work dynamically, so I would need to:

1. Get all the database servers in the SharePoint farm
2. Get all the SharePoint machines in the farm

The problem is that cmdlet

> Get-SPServer

… returns all the servers together, mixed up, including the SMTP servers.

And with

> Get-SPDatabase | Select NormalizedDataSource

I get them multiple times. What do I have to change to do this right?

Answer (score 8):

```
Get-SPServer | where {$_.Role -ne "Invalid"}
```

That will not return SQL or SMTP servers (or other non-configured servers).

Answer (score 5):

Probably you're looking for **Get-Unique** cmdlet:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315329.aspx

Thus please, try running this command:

```
Get-SPDatabase | Select NormalizedDataSource | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```